# The user mode of DM is not updated after changing the global tag group

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all:
I'd like to change the user mode at Help->User Mode from Regular to Power user by using script (see below). After running the script, the global tag group has changed, but the tick at Help->User Mode doesn't change. It seems that the tag group can be changed by clicking Help->User Mode->Power User, but the tick at Help->User Mode can not be reversely affected by the global tag group. Does anyone know how to change the tick position by using script?

```
TagGroup global_tag_group = GetPersistentTagGroup()
String tag_path = "Private:Application Defaults:Application Mode"
String application_mode = "Expert"
global_tag_group.TagGroupSetTagAsString(tag_path, application_mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

`ChooseMenuItem("Help","User Mode","Power User")`

or

`ChooseMenuItem("Help","User Mode","Regular")`

Or you can alternatively use:

`ApplicationSetApplicationMode("Regular")`

or

`ApplicationSetApplicationMode("Expert")`